# Chrome DevTools extension can't access storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-storage

I'm writing a Chrome extension where I would like to access the Chrome Storage API from the Devtools page. The chrome.storage.local variable (with the get/set functions) are available, but when I call them the callback never get's called. When I use my background page to access the storage API it works as expected.

I could, of course, send the request via the background page and pass it to the Devtools page through messages but I'm looking for a more cleaner approach. Am I doing something wrong?
I hope that you understand my question, to illustrate my problem I have created a little sample of what I'm coping with, ready for download here; http://g2f.nl/0w2kko9.

It includes the following test which verifies that the API is available but does not work as expected;

```
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += "chrome.storage.local.set = " + !!chrome.storage.local.set
+ "<br>chrome.storage.local.get = " + !!chrome.storage.local.get;

chrome.storage.local.set( {'foo' : 'bar'} , function () {
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += '<br>foo = bar';
});

setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += '<br>That was one second';
    chrome.storage.local.get('foo', function (result) {
        document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += '<br>foo = ' + result;
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Include the sample code in the question; link-only code is not allowed on SO.

Comment: Curiously, it works in a detached Dev Tools window. May be a bug.

Comment: You're right, hmm thats weird!

Comment: Try it on a Canary/dev build of Chrome. If it reproduces, file a bug at https://crbug.com/new

Comment: I always use Canary. I'll just file a bug then, thanks!

Comment: You probably should reply with a link to the bug ticket if you do.

Comment: Bugreport: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=405096